# Required python libraries for the QGIS official plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Is there a list of required python modules for the official plugins of the LTR version?

Comment: As far as i know, there is not such a list. But, if you look at the windows setup.ini, there is a list of dependencies and you can use these as reference. download https://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/x86/setup.ini and search for @ qgis-ltr and @ qgis-ltr-common. Because the python-packages found there are the default for all plattforms, any plugins will be based upon these or need an additional install. For what purpose do you need it?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I installed the LTR and when I opened I got plugin errors so I went to check. After installing the third package I came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this list:
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html#toc6 did the job.

**That's the list for Arch:**
yay -S python2-dateutil python2-future gdal python2-gdal python2-httplib2 python2-jinja python2-markupsafe python2-mock python2-nose2 python2-owslib python2-psycopg2 python2-pygments python2-pyproj  python2-pyqt4 python2-requests python2-sip python2-six python2-termcolor python2-tzlocal python2-yaml python2-plotly

Some of the packages are from AUR so you must use an AUR helper.